# Какой будет xpath у элемента

Tags: xpath

Какой будет xpath у элемента, если нужно чтобы учитывалось и B2B develop и Поставщик и Одобрена?
Пока получилось `//p[text()= 'Одобрена']/preceding::div[text()='B2B develop']`
Но здесь не учитывается поле Поставщик

[image: дерево]

Comment: в каждом нормальном браузере есть опция получить xpath элемента

Comment: я в курсе. если бы там было все просто, то я бы не спрашивал

Comment: В конечном итоге какой именно элемент нужно получить: `p`, `div`?